# Show values with specific status

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I am running the following query:

```
Select a.Location, ProcType, Status, f.Code, p.Day, Start, Stop, 
(Case When Stop IS NULL then Start else  Stop end) as LastState, 
(case when Type like 'Type1%' then Status else 'NULL' end) as Type1,
(case when Type like 'Type2%' then Status else 'NULL' end) as Type2
from dbo.table1 a
inner join Database..table2 p on Name = 'RunDay' and 
a.Location = p.Location and p.Value = a.SomeRunDay
left outer join [Database].[dbo].[table3] f on a.File_number = 
f.File_number 
where a.Location is not NULL
ORDER BY Location
```

And the results generated are:
** This table only shows values for one location, I have hundreds of them in my table

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------|Location|ProcType|Status|Code| Day | Start | Stop |LastState|Type1|Type2| 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Type1_A|Done| A |2018/03/01|15:58|16:32|2018/03/01 16:32|Done|NULL| 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Type1_B|Done| B |2018/03/01|15:59|16:32|2018/03/01 16:34|Done|NULL| 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Type2_A_Loop|Done| A |2018/03/01|16:00|16:38|2018/03/01 16:38|NULL|Done| 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|1 |Type1_A_Loop|Processing| B |2018/03/11|15:59|16:32|2018/03/11 16:34|NULL|Processing|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Type2_B|Processing| B |2018/03/11|15:59|16:32|2018/03/11 16:34|NULL|Processing|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to find a way to view only the latest `ProcType`, the ones that show
`Processing` taking into consideration that the `LastState` column is showing the most recent state. In other words, I want to see results that contain 'loop' only with the `Processing` status.

The solution that is running in my head would be something like

```
Select MAX (LastState) from dbo.table1
Where Status = 'Done'
```

and perform some sort of union..? I need some help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
  from ( Select a.Location, ProcType, Status, f.Code, p.Day, Start, Stop, 
                isnull(Stop, Start) as LastState, 
                case when Type like 'Type1%' then Status else 'NULL' end as Type1,
                case when Type like 'Type2%' then Status else 'NULL' end as Type2,
                row_number() over (partition by a.Location order by isnull(Stop, Start) desc) as rn
           from dbo.table1 a
          inner join Database..table2 p 
             on Name = 'RunDay' 
            and Status = 'Done'
            and a.Location = p.Location 
            and p.Value = a.SomeRunDay
           left outer join [Database].[dbo].[table3] f 
             on a.File_number = f.File_number 
       ) tt 
 where tt.rn = 1
 ORDER BY tt.Location
```

Comment: Thank you @paparazzo but when I run this, it displays `Done` in the `Type1` column and I am actually looking for the `Processing` ones.

Comment: @Notsoeasy Answer is only as good as the question.  Question is not clear.  This is a framework for you to apply (or not).